# Jmeter test with Junit sampler always recording 0 bytes and 0 latency

Tags: java, junit, jmeter

I'm running a few Junit tests through a Junit sampler and each of these tests is posting and receiving some data from a server using HTTPURLConnection. Since Jmeter manuals suggest that the Junit tests are directly run by Jmeter, I was expecting to see the Throughput ( bytes sent / received ) and latency in the results. However, my results are always showing 0 for bytes and latency.

What should I do to properly record these values in my result? Thanks!

Here is the simplified form of unit test I'm using :

```
@Test
public void testCreateValidTestRequest()
{
TestResponse  response = TestUtils.sendRequest();
assertEquals("Error!!! Test request failed",200,response.getResponseCode());
}
```

and inside the TestUtils class,

```
public static TestResponse sendRequest()
{
TestResponse response=new TestResponse();
URLConnection connection;
try
{
URL url=new URL(test_url);
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();  
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream wr=new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
wr.write(message);
wr.flush();
wr.close();
int responseCode=((HttpURLConnection)connection).getResponseCode();
response.setResponseCode(responseCode);
return response;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code you were using?

Comment: I had the same problem with Java request and us I understood you can only have response time using java request, junit request because JMeter based on sending and received http Get and Post and only for those you can have all parameters (latency, throughput)

Comment: I have edited the question to include the test code that I'm using. Thanks!